# Toggle icon in IconButton

Tags: flutter

I am trying to toggle the `IconButton` icon when pressed on it. This is what I have so far:

```
class _AppsScreenState extends State<AppsScreen> {
  late Future<AllApps> activateApps;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    activateApps = getActivatedApps();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    IconData iconData = Icons.grid_view;

    void _toggleViewIcon() {
      setState(() {
        if (iconData == Icons.grid_view) {
          iconData = Icons.list;
        } else {
          iconData = Icons.grid_view;
        }
      });
    }

    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: const Text('Apps'),
          primary: false,
          toolbarHeight: 50,
          leading: IconButton(
            tooltip: 'Toggle view',
            icon: Icon(iconData),
            onPressed: _toggleViewIcon,
          ),
          actions: <Widget>[
            Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 20.0),
                child: IconButton(
                  tooltip: 'Refresh',
                  icon: const Icon(Icons.refresh),
                  onPressed: () {
                    setState(() {
                      activateApps = getActivatedApps();
                    });
                  },
                )),
            Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 20.0),
                child: IconButton(
                  tooltip: 'Add or remove apps',
                  icon: const Icon(Icons.add),
                  onPressed: () {
                    setState(() {
                      activateApps = getActivatedApps();
                    });
                  },
                )),
          ],
        ),
        primary: false,
        body: Column(children: []));
  }
}
```

The button never toggles. I am not sure what I am doing wrong here. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`setState` will rebuild the widget, i.e the `build` function will be called again, thus the `iconData` variable will be set again to `Icons.grid_view`

move the `iconData` declaration and the function `_toggleViewIcon` outside of the build function

Answer (score 0):

iconData variable will be set again to Icons.grid_view each time when you call set state if it put inside build method, so declare it outside build method

```
class _AppsScreenState extends State<AppsScreen> {
  late Future<AllApps> activateApps;
  IconData iconData = Icons.grid_view;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    activateApps = getActivatedApps();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    void _toggleViewIcon() {
      setState(() {
        if (iconData == Icons.grid_view) {
          iconData = Icons.list;
        } else {
          iconData = Icons.grid_view;
        }
      });
    }

    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: const Text('Apps'),
          primary: false,
          toolbarHeight: 50,
          leading: IconButton(
            tooltip: 'Toggle view',
            icon: Icon(iconData),
            onPressed: _toggleViewIcon,
          ),
          actions: <Widget>[
            Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 20.0),
                child: IconButton(
                  tooltip: 'Refresh',
                  icon: const Icon(Icons.refresh),
                  onPressed: () {
                    setState(() {
                      activateApps = getActivatedApps();
                    });
                  },
                )),
            Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 20.0),
                child: IconButton(
                  tooltip: 'Add or remove apps',
                  icon: const Icon(Icons.add),
                  onPressed: () {
                    setState(() {
                      activateApps = getActivatedApps();
                    });
                  },
                )),
          ],
        ),
        primary: false,
        body: Column(children: []));
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use SteamBuilder instead, if you want to change a bit of space, but it will rebuild all widgets

Comment: Thanks for the info and Welcome to Stackoverflow! Also, just an FYI, this looks more like a comment than an answer. Can you move this to the comments section under my question and delete this. You might get downvotes for this.